# application not working after debug session and reset stm32

Tags: debugging, arm, stm32, cortex-m, keil

I'm new member of this community.
I've a custom board using stm32l431cct6 microcontroller and I have a strange iussue after program the boards with Keil uVision or Eclipse IDE.
I'm working with a firmware made by another guy, and I saw that debug session works fine. In other words, after Debug session and after Power on Reset, the application works without problmes.

One time, during debug session, the cable with JTAG interface was disconnected. After this event my board had problems with flash programming with Keil or Eclipse. Then the Cortex-M4 processor was in AMR mode, and to solve the situation I used J-Link Commander to unlock the device. After the unlock I was able to re-flash the board with USART probe.

Now this is the situation:

- If I program the firmware with USART using an application based on ST Flash Loader, all works fine.
- If I try to debug my board with Keil, using the same settings made from the other guy, the flash programming is done, and I'm able to debug the code. **But** after reset (I switch off and on the power supply) the application doesn't start! It seems that's a problem with erase&program of the flash memory. It's strange because before the "accident of the JTAG", all works fine.

Do you have any advice to solve this situation?

Comment: Have you accidentally changed the "option bytes"?

Comment: Hi, you could improve readability of your post if you use "- If" instad of "-If" (space missing to make a list of it)

Comment: thanks ! How can I view the option bytes?

Comment: If debugging works and the "standalone" program does not please have a look at the linker file (or the generate map file). Where in the flash is your program placed?
(Normally is should be 0x08000000)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use 2 application installed on the flash. The first is my bootloader placed in 0x08000000. The main application is placed in 0x0800A000. I check all 2 linker file (.sct in Keil environment) and they seems fine. Let's consider that the system worked fine before accidently removing JTAG during debugging. Any suggestions?

Comment: So you have the bootloader and the application on your chip.
If you program the application via bootloader everything is fine.
If you program the application via debugger you can debug/run it, but after a reset the application does not start?

Comment: Exactly! @theSealion you center the iussue!

Comment: That sounds that either your debugging deletes the bootloader or the bootloaders checks the application firmware before he starts it (an the debug firmware is not recognized as valid)